# PUT http://localhost:8080/staf/3 500 (Internal Server Error) when edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I made a frontend using react.js. When I want to create a data edit function and I use codeigniter 4 for backend. I get an error like the following :

*PUT http://localhost:8080/staf/3 500 (Internal Server Error)*

Is there anyone who can help solve this problem?

My StafsUpdate.js

```
export default function StafsUpdate() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const axios = require('axios')

  
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [staf_nama, setNama] = useState('');
  const [staf_jabatan, setJabatan] = useState('');
  const [staf_email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [staf_telp, setTelp] = useState('');

  const [dbo_staf, setStaf] = useState([]);


 useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/staf/"+id)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setNama(result.staf.staf_nama)
          setJabatan(result.staf.staf_jabatan)
          setEmail(result.staf.staf_email)
          setTelp(result.staf.staf_telp)
        }
      )
  }, [id])

  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = {
      staf_id: id,
      staf_nama: staf_nama,
      staf_jabatan: staf_jabatan,
      staf_telp: staf_telp,
    }
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/staf/'+id, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/form-data',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
   
    .then(
      (result) => {
        alert(result['message'])
        if (result['status'] === 'ok') {
          window.location.href = '/stafs';
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

This is server code
My Controller :

```
public function update($id = null)
    {
        $model = new StafModel();
        $input = $this->request->getRawInput();
        $data = [
          
            // 'staf_admin' => $input['staf_admin'],
            'staf_nama' => $input['staf_nama'],
            'staf_jabatan' => $input['staf_jabatan'],
            'staf_email' => $input['staf_email'],
            'staf_telp' => $input['staf_telp'],
        ];
        $model->update($id, $data);

        $response = [
            'status'   => 200,
            'error'    => null,
            'messages' => [
                'success' => 'Data Updated'
            ]
        ];
        return $this->respond($response);
    }
```

Comment: The response code of 500 says it's an internal server error. But this is your client code--where's the server code?

Comment: @ggorlen I have added the server code

Comment: Thanks. It's still not enough to say what's wrong. Firstly, I'd tag it PHP and codeigniter and secondly, I'd share the error message from the server log. Thrdly, I'd provide a definition for `StafModel` and anything else that's relevant on the server.